# Sending replyToApplicationShouldTerminate to NSApplication in Swift

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsapplication

Here is my AppDelegate.swift. I implement the applicationShouldTerminate protocol from NSApplication. Which answer I give depends on the status of is.Started in the mainWindowController. (This is the SpeakLine example from Cocoa Programming for OS X: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide 5/e—I'm trying to take the example one step further and keep the program from being allowed to quit while the talking is going on.)

What I want to do is change TerminateReply.TerminateCancel to TerminateReply.TermianteLater and then send NSApplication the replyToApplicationShouldTerminate(true) signal when the talking is done. As it stands now in the MainControllerWindow.swift class I have a function set up to handle state changes in the Speech Synthesizer and that's where I want to call it.

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {


    var mainWindowController: MainWindowController?

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {

        let mainWindowController = MainWindowController()
        mainWindowController.showWindow(self)
        self.mainWindowController = mainWindowController

    }

    func applicationShouldTerminate(sender: NSApplication) -> NSApplicationTerminateReply {
        if (mainWindowController!.isStarted) {
            return NSApplicationTerminateReply.TerminateCancel
        } else {
        return NSApplicationTerminateReply.TerminateNow
        }
    }

}
```

The trouble is, when I put it here, I get an error.

```
   var isStarted: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            updateButtons()
            NSApplication.replyToApplicationShouldTerminate(true)
        }
    }
```

it tells me I can't use a bool. It also tells me I can't use an Objective C bool when I try to put YES. How do I tell NSApplication it's OK to quit now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you should change

```
NSApplication.replyToApplicationShouldTerminate(true)
```

to

```
NSApplication.sharedApplication().replyToApplicationShouldTerminate(true)
```

since `replyToApplicationShouldTerminate` is a instance method rather then a class method.

Answer (score 0):

my tow cents for swift 5.x:

```
        NSApplication.shared.reply(toApplicationShouldTerminate: true)
```